# Newbie: Where to put my MQTT applications?

Tags: linux, directory

**The bigger scenario:** A Linux machine should run automatically several MQTT clients. One of them should act as an *application server* that listens at the topic and delivers the external devices their own MQTT client applications. (The device will ask through its fixed *loader*.) So, there should be static subdirectories with the installation images for the devices (named according to MAC or using some mapping of MAC to subdirectory).

**The question:** What is the recommended directory location for such files by convention? Should it be somewhere in `/usr`? Or should I consider it *configuration files* (although not for this Linux machine) and put it somewhere in `/etc`?

And is it OK to put the active part (that is the MQTT client that plays the role of the **application server** at the same directories? Where can I read more about the recommendations/conventions?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) which is a section of the [Linux Standards Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base).

This sets out where files should be placed based on type/usage.

Comment: Correction of my previous incorrect comment (that was deleted). I have copied the binary (actually the executable Python script) into `/usr/local/bin`, its `my_script.config` into `/usr/local/etc`, and the subdirectory with static files into `/usr/local/etc/my_script/`. (As the virtual machine was freshly installed, the `/usr/local/` was completely empty.) Is that a correct/acceptable approach?